# Is it possible to reserialize a single item with Unicorn?

Tags: unicorn

I had this issue when syncing a configuration on one of my projects:

"You can resolve this warning by reserializing the master:/sitecore/content/Modules/Links/Charts/Chart 1/Symptoms/Results item, or manually removing the deleted field value from the serialized item."

this message got me thinking. I know I can reserialize the whole configuration and all items of it get reserialized but do it for just a single item I wouldn`t know how to do it. anyone knows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's totally possible. When an item is controlled by Unicorn, you can use the Developer tab controls in the Sitecore ribbon to do partial syncing or partial reserialization.

Unicorn takes over the standard Sitecore serialization in those cases.

See https://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/09/Unicorn-3-What-s-new/#Unicorn-enabled-serialize-commands